# How to retrieve data from two tables in a search function

Tags: php, mysql, search

So I have this simple search code

```
<div id="page">
    <!-- start content -->
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
    // search in all table columns
    // using concat mysql function
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `pdspersonalinfo` WHERE CONCAT(`personid`, `surname`, `firstname`, `sex`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);

}
 else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `pdspersonalinfo`";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ucwd");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP HTML TABLE DATA SEARCH</title>
        <style>
            table,tr,th,td
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="searchtrain[orig].php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search" autocomplete="off"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>

            <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Surame</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Sex</th>
                    <th>Training</th>
                </tr>

      <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['personid'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['surname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['firstname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['sex'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['traintitle'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
</div>
```

But I want my `search_results` to retrieve data from two `tables` having a common column

My first table is named `pdspersonlinfo` and has the following rows `personid, position, day, month, year, surname, firstname, middlename, sex`

My second table is named `pdstrain` and has the following rows `personid, trainid, traintitle, trainfrom, trainto`

When I search, for example the name Jacob, the data `surname`,`firstname` `middlename` - `traintitle` will be retrieved

I'm very much a beginner on `php` and `mysql`. I hope this can be comprehended.

I thank you in advance ^_^

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for INNER JOIN: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-an-inner-join.php

Answer (score 0):

You need a join.

```
SELECT a.something, b.something 
FROM tableA a JOIN tableB b 
ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Thanks fred, i didnt format it as it was a one liner so didnt think it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables in your select query

```
SELECT
I.surname, I.firstname, I.middlename, P.traintitle
FROM pdspersonlinfo I
LEFT JOIN pdstrain P ON P.personid = I.personid
WHERE CONCAT(I.personid, I.surname, I.firstname, I.sex) LIKE '%valueToSearch%'
```

Don't forget to properly escape the user inputted search value!

Comment: I'm having errors on this part `mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)` tho

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Never mind, ^_^  I'd seen what was wrong. Thanks